# Firefox for Android can't stop touchscroll

Tags: javascript, firefox, scroll

I've been searching the internet and it seems like this problem didn't always exist on Firefox for android.

I need t stop the touch scroll on a specific element.

I've tried

```
myElement.addEventListener('touchstart'),function(event){event.preventDefault();}); 
myElement.addEventListener('touchmove'),function(event){event.preventDefault();});
```

And

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart'),function(event){event.preventDefault();}); 
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove'),function(event){event.preventDefault();}); 
document.addEventListener('touchstart'),function(event){event.preventDefault();}); 
document.addEventListener('touchmove'),function(event){event.preventDefault();});
```

Combinations of those work for Chrome and Safari. What's up with Firefox?
Still scrolls. What am I missing?

Comment: On this page I've found that FF scroll can be prevented on touchstart only: http://blog.mobiscroll.com/working-with-touch-events/

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that you just have these events, and try avoiding click because it confuses the browser sometimes: [touchstart touchend touchcancel touchleave touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Touch_events)

And I think preventDefault is not the better. I shoul use stopImmediatePropagation instead, that is like a preventDefault + stopPropagation

Hope it helps!